# Warning: Your Magento folder does not have sufficient write permissions

Tags: magento

I am new to Magento, I am trying to install a theme via magento connect manager, I copy and paste the extension key then click install and then proceed.I get error 'Warning: Your Magento folder does not have sufficient write permissions.'

please give some solution .Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Solution is provided on my last comment http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33363561/magento-folder-and-file-permissions/40235627#40235627

Answer (score 33, accepted):

go to Magento home directory and just give permissions for your webroot.

```
e.g. (in ubuntu) : sudo chown -R www-data .
```

You could also change the permissions

```
chmod 777  -R downloader/*
```

I hope it helps.

[EDIT]

How about in your magento directory (use `sudo` for below commands if required.):

```
find . -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;
find . -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \;
```

For the normal operation or installation of a Magento store, only 2 folders need to be writable:

```
/media - for web accessible files, such as product images
/var - for temporary (cache, session) and import/export files
```

[Source here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/magento_filesystem_permissions)

Comment: Thank you very much for your Post.I tried changing permissions to several folders in server,it still not working.

Comment: how about:      
find . -type d -exec chmod 775 {} ;

find . -type f -exec chmod 664 {} ;

Comment: Second solution helped a lot. fixed issue.Thank you once again medina  .

Comment: I followed these steps and fixed my issue. Thanks medina 1) sudo chown -R www-data . 
 2) sudo find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
 3) sudo find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
 4) sudo chmod 777  -R downloader/*

Comment: If you get a `find: missing argument to -exec` error, you need to put a \ (backslash) in front of the `;`

Comment: Not sure why you guys are using 775 for dirs... http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/groups/227/resetting_file_permissions

Comment: I just have access via ftp. Is there anyway I can achieve this without doing it manually?

Comment: @ReidBlomquist that's now a dead link

Comment: NEVER chmod a folder or a file on your server to 777. It means that any user can toss in a malicious script that gives them access to everything: files, database, etc.

Answer (score 10):

To reset file permissions run:

```
find . -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;
find . -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \;
chmod 777 -R downloader var media
```

Comment: Thanks setting parent folder to 777 as well, worked for me.

Answer (score 9):

In my case this wasn't enough. I had to set 777 permision also to parent folder - public_html (NOT recursive).

Comment: Something wrong with the owning users/groups if you have to do so.

Comment: Very bad idea to set 777 permission to folder. Security issue.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a complete shell script that I wrote to help you setup permissions/ownership of your Magento Installation :  [mage-set-perms](https://gist.github.com/amineasli/8bde97270d20ffe790f1)

The shell script is based on the recommendation of Magento official article found [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/install/installer-privileges_after.html)

Answer (score 0):

With me works with this reset permissions:

```
chmod -R 777 media/
chmod -R 755 var/
```

I follow some instructions in this url:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/groups/227/resetting_file_permissions

Comment: You should never chmod to 777. It means that any user can just mess with your files and introduce a virus or any other malicious code, like one that will expose/steal all your customer info or delete all your transaction history.

Answer (score 0):

I used the other solutions listed, e.g.:

```
cd /var/www/html
find . -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;
find . -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \; 
chmod -R 777 downloader var media
```

But I also had to do:

```
chown apache:apache /var/www/html
```

Since the web root directory was still owned by 'root:root' and causing problems (by continuing to display the Magento error message).

Answer (score 0):

Of all of these what worked was 
`public_html# find . -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;` 
and
`chgrp -R www-data`

This returns the ability to use Local file system as opposed to FTP

755 does not have group create and delete permissions so 775 worked

Return /media and /var permissions back to `/public_html/media# find . -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;`
`/public_html/var# find . -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;`