# Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Mage_Core_Exception'

Tags: php, xml, database, magento, admin

I have a brand new [Magento](http://www.magentocommerce.com/) shop and want to go online but I'm getting this error very often:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message '
>   is not a directory or not readable by this user' in
>   /home/pimpjep/public_html/app/Mage.php:594 Stack trace: #0
>   /home/pimpjep/public_html/app/Mage.php(278): Mage::throwException(' is
>   not a direc...') #1 /home/pimpjep/public_html/app/Mage.php(752):
>   Mage::setRoot() #2 /home/pimpjep/public_html/app/Mage.php(692):
>   Mage::isInstalled() #3 /home/pimpjep/public_html/index.php(89):
>   Mage::run('pimpjephone') #4 {main} thrown in
>   /home/pimpjep/public_html/app/Mage.php on line 594

How do I get rid of it?

Comment: seems like a directory permission issue. Follow the magento install steps and chown the needed folders to the right permissions.

Comment: This may will help you  http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/5976/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16097724/warning-your-magento-folder-does-not-have-sufficient-write-permissions/16097821#16097821